# ios:click on navigation button overlaps views on tabbar view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My application is bit simple But as new to iOS i am not able to detect where the actual problem is .iam having a tabbar controller having four buttons and for each button i have taken a navigation controller and i attach a  view controller for all.The problem is when i click on the navigation bar button item .the view appears on the top of the tabbar view .When i click tabbar button B and came back to tabbar button the same view when i clicked on the navigation button appears but not the actual view of tab.In the tabbar delegate i have given like this

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item

 {

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But still i am facing the same problem .Please provide me a solution if possibe with a sample code

Comment: You want to show the root VC of each tab on tab item click?

Comment: yes exactly but for that i am  double clicking the tabbar button in my case now .But should click only once for getting the root view

Comment: This is a very odd requirement. What if you intend to navigate to detailed screens from this view? It would be a very bad user experience if you show the first screen on every tab switch. Or if you are simply intending to show five views, then better not use a tab bar controller at all. Go for some custom control or try creating a simple view with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add `didSelectViewController` delegate method of Tabbar and add code to pop to root view controller like below

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: my case only above delegate is calling i.e -(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item. the above method u have given is not reaching there break point

Comment: did you subclassed `UITabBarController`? set delegate to `UITabBarController`. And ` didSelectItem:` is method from `UITabBar` which is already handled by tabbar controller. Try setting delegate to tabbarcontroller instead of uitabbar

Comment: i have taken suclass of of UITabbarcontroller and ser self.tabbarcontroller.delegate to self and still its not working

Comment: then try `[self. selectedViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ` in `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method.

Comment: tried and i print self. selectedViewController.navigationController in console its showing nil

Comment: what about `self.selectedViewController` this is also nil?

Comment: No i am getting  like this  <UINavigationController: 0x15633500> i think that means its not nil

Comment: means the selected view controller itself is a navigation controller. So try `[self.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: No visible interface for UIviewcontroller declares the selector poptoviewcontroller aninmater   this is error iam getting

Comment: you got `<UINavigationController: 0x15633500>` when logging  `self.selectedViewController.navigationController ` or `self.selectedViewController`?